# How to set prefered view resolution when mixing GSP and JSON views

Tags: json, angularjs, rest, grails, grails3

I'm maintaining a grails 3.3.8 app using the angularjs profile.

The REST API and angularjs assets are provided by the same grails application. For now I don't want to split the app into two applications.

The app uses JSON views to render the JSON response for the resources.
The app also uses the GSP view plugin to provide the initial `index.gsp` to serve the angularjs app.

Due to the usage of the GSP view plugin the app always renders the default gsp error views instead of using the JSON views in case of `500`, `404`, `401`, ... errors.

When I remove the `grails-gsp` plugin, all request are served with a JSON response. Also in case of an error. But then the `index.gsp` can't be rendered.

Is it possible to tell the grails app that it should use the JSON views by default and just in case of the index it should use the gsp view?

Update:
I would like to render views directly from URLMapping without creating a controller.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to tell the grails app that it should use the JSON
>   views by default and just in case of the index it should use the gsp
>   view?

Yes.  You can serve many different view types from the same app, including GSON Views working along side GSP Views.

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/webjsonviews.

If you run that app and send a request to http://localhost:8080/person/index with your browser, you will see HTML rendered which was server side rendered using GSP.

If you send a request to http://localhost:8080/person/index.json with your browser, you will see the JSON rendered using GSON Views.

This will render HTML:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/person/index
```

This will render JSON:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/person/index.json
```

This will render JSON:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8080/person/index
```

If you would like the default content type to be `application/json`, you can add the following to the `PersonController`:

```
static responseFormats = ['json', 'html']
```

That will cause the following to return JSON instead of HTML:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/person/index
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I already know that I could set the response format. I would like to render the view directly using URL mapping without adding an extra controller. Should have put this detail into my question. When looking at the code, it looks like the `jspViewResolver` has the highest priority and will be used when available.

Comment: "I would like to render the view directly using URL mapping without adding an extra controller." - I misunderstood the original question.  Sorry for the noise.